# Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core 3.21.61 using UDT Oracle 11g with c# .net 6

Tags: c#, oracle, user-defined-types

I'm currently working on upgrading code from .NET 4.5.1 to .NET 6.  Currently working on database functionality. In .NET 4.5.1, I regularly used Oracle UDT as both input and output parameters without issue. However, for the life of me I can't get it to work on .NET 6. I'm using an Oracle 11g database, and I'm kind of thinking/hoping that the database version is the issue since there is an Oracle database upgrade planned in the coming months. Otherwise, I might have to delay the upgrade.

I think my code is pretty straight forward. The UDTTypes are defined in Oracle (and working in .NET 4.5.1)  Logically then, that shouldn't be the issue.  Abbreviated, they look as follows

```
create or replace TYPE "WBH_PLATELIST" IS TABLE OF WBH_PLATEOBJ;

create or replace TYPE "WBH_PLATEOBJ" AS OBJECT 
(
    LPID                VARCHAR2(15 BYTE),
    ITEM                VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
    ...
)
```

I have a package with a procedure with signature as below that works just fine.

```
PROCEDURE GetInventoryPlates( p_CustId    IN varchar2,
                              p_Plate     OUT WBH_PLATELIST);
```

I'm using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core v.3.21.61.  My C# code looks like

```
string packageProc = "WBH_DEVELOPMENT.GetInventoryPlates";

OracleParameter clientparam = new OracleParameter() 
{   ParameterName = "p_CustId",
    Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, 
    Value = "XZXXX" 
};
OracleParameter plateparam = new OracleParameter()
{
    ParameterName = "p_Plate",
    DbType = DbType.Object,
    OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Object,
    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
    UdtTypeName = "ALPS.WBH_PLATELIST",
};

try
{
    using (OracleConnection SqlCon = new OracleConnection(@"Data Source=x.x.x.x:xxx/test;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx"))
    {
        using (OracleCommand SqlCmd = new OracleCommand(packageProc, SqlCon))
        {
            if (paramList != null)
            {
                SqlCmd.BindByName = true;
                SqlCmd.Parameters.Add(clientparam);
                SqlCmd.Parameters.Add(plateparam);
            }
            SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlCmd.Connection.Open();
            SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
catch (OracleException ex)
{
    string log = ex.Message;

}
```

Seems like no matter what I do, I get the following error as soon as the ExecuteNonQuery function is called.

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 13:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_TYPE_SHAPE'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot recall now the source, but I am pretty sure, that I saw somewhere, that you need to have DB version at least 12.1 to use UDTs with managed driver (both, normal and "core").

Comment: I don't know what the minimum version is, but I was coming here to report that on a test version of Oracle 19 I have the UDTs working with Managed Driver and .NET 6.0.  And frustratingly, Oracle AQ Messages only seem to be supported up to .NET 4.7. 
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/odpnt/OracleAQMessageClass.html#GUID-16A1F29B-CF63-47A8-8A9B-0A881E3C97CC